# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, undefined

I'm working on pulling data from a json object and then displaying the information on the front end. What is the best way to wrap the code below to check to see if the variable SKU is undefined or unavailable then to not run the code at all.

On Google Chrome, I get an Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property "dm" of undefined based on the code below.

```
var SKU = "556520000";
var dimBreak = obj[SKU]["dm"];
for(var i = 0; i < dimBreak.length; i++){
    const dimAll = dimBreak[i];
    let entries = Object.entries(dimAll);
    
    for(const [prop, val] of entries) {
        console.log(prop, val);
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

---

Based on a comment below

I've tried below which gives same error as above.

```
var dimBreak = obj[SKU]["dm"];
console.log(dimBreak);

if(typeof dimBreak === 'undefined') {
    console.log("Is undefined");
} else {
    console.log("Is defined");
}
```

This code below however runs

```
var dimBreak = "Test";
console.log(dimBreak);

if(typeof dimBreak === 'undefined') {
    console.log("Is undefined");
} else {
    console.log("Is defined");
}
```

---

Object that is used

```
{
   "556520000":{
      "lmin":"35",
      "dm":[
         {
            "Width":"147"
         },
         {
            "Depth":"10"
         },
         {
            "Height":"137"
         }
      ],
      "lmax":"68",
   }
}
```

Comment: How is `obj` look like?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detecting an undefined object property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509/detecting-an-undefined-object-property)

Comment: Thanks @BillyBrown but it doesn't seem to work. I've run it in two parts and the latter one runs but the first one throws the same error as above.

Comment: Post your _obj_ Object

Comment: @Bala thanks, posted in main question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to check SKU is present in the object, if not add a check. Your code seems to be working(You can see below)

```js
var obj = {
   "556520000":{
      "lmin":"35",
      "dm":[
         {
            "Width":"147"
         },
         {
            "Depth":"10"
         },
         {
            "Height":"137"
         }
      ],
      "lmax":"68",
   }
}

var SKU = "556520000";
if(obj[SKU]){
  var dimBreak = obj[SKU]["dm"];
  for(var i = 0; i < dimBreak.length; i++){
      const dimAll = dimBreak[i];
      let entries = Object.entries(dimAll);

      for(const [prop, val] of entries) {
          console.log(prop, val);
      }
  }
} else {
  console.log(SKU+' is not defined');
}
```